# Increasing a value, but not exceeding another value sql

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Hello I am trying to write an sql statement that checks to see if an increased value is higher than that of another.

I am using MySQL and Python.

```
Response=int(input("Use Medicine? Y/N "))
if Response==("Y") or Response==("y"):
   healedvalue=random.randint(1,3)
   GetHealth=("UPDATE activechar SET currhealth=currhealth+%s BUT NOT HIGHER THAN currmaxhealth WHERE acharID=%s")
   mycursor.execute(GetHealth,(healedvalue,id))
   mydb.commit()
```

**Desired Results:**

For example, if `currhealth=1`  and `healedvalue=3` and `currmaxhealth=5` then `currheath` will be updated to `4`.

Yet if `currhealth=4`  and `healedvalue=3` and `currmaxhealth=5` then `currheath` will be updated to `5`, as `currhealth` cannot exceed `5`.

**Table:**

[activechar table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sutg7.png)

Comment: Sure np @GordonLinoff

Comment: What is the code doing now, and how is that different from what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`LEAST()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least), which "returns the smallest (minimum-valued) argument":

```
UPDATE activechar
SET currhealth = LEAST(currhealth + %s, currmaxhealth)
WHERE acharID = %s
```

Comment: Was about to answer with an IF(), didn't know LEAST() Existed, thats nice! +1